# UWP application - Publish the same app in LOB and public Windows store account

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store, lob

I am developing UWP application.I want to publish the application as LOB application in one of my client's enterprise account. I have few questions:

1. Will it possible to publish the same application on the windows with different package name for other customers?
2. Will it possible to publish the same application on the windows with same package name for other customers?
3. Does the windows do any verification on the code level?
4. Same application means Name, publisherid and publisher display name are common in appx.manifest file , but the reserved app's names(two apps) is different in the stores(Normal store and LOB store). Will it possible to do? Does the windows allow to upload like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I want to publish the application as LOB application in one of my client's enterprise account.*

This account should be a [developer account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/opening-a-developer-account).

1) Will it possible to publish the same application on the windows with different package name for other customers ?

When the package is uploaded in [Microsoft Partner Center](https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/windows/overview), Partner Center identifies the uploaded package according to the elements that declare the identity of your app in the manifest of the package. Identify elements of each app is unique,and you can't change them in the manifest if you still want to publish it. If the identity in the manifest remains the same, but only the name of the package after packaging is changed, the upload is not affected.

2) Will it possible to publish the same application on the windows with same package name for other customers ?

The same app can be used by different enterprises, but only one app with the same name can exist in the store. Once LOB distribution is selected, the usual Visibility options will be replaced with a list of the enterprises to which you can publish exclusive apps. Please go to [Submit LOB apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/distribute-lob-apps-to-enterprises#submit-lob-apps) for more details.

3) Does the windows do any verification on the code leave?

After you successfully upload the app's packages and submit the app for certification, the packages are queued for testing. [Derive from [app certification process]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/the-app-certification-process)

Comment: @ DasiyTian MSFT
Thank you for your help. It would be helpful If you clarify my below doubts also. 1) Can use the same developer account to publish LOB apps for my customer and publish the apps(others) in normal windows store ? 2) Same application means Name, publisherid and publisher display name are common in appx.manifest file , but the reserved app's names(two apps) is different in the store. Will it possible to do? 3) Will it possible to change the already distributed apps from windows store to LOB apps

Comment: 1)Publishing LOB apps have no effect on publishing other apps in the Store with the same developer account. 2)it is better not to do this .3)Yes,it is

Comment: Thank you @DasiyTian, I hope regarding the point 2, The windows store won't reject incase if we submit two apps since one my customer does want  the app in their markets.